# Convert Excel Raster into Shapefile

Tags: excel, shapefile

I have an excel table in which each cell represents (NOT CONTAINS) a coordinate-pair and a value. For example Sheet 1:Cell A1 contains an X-coordinate which increases 25m downwards; Sheet 2: Cell A1 contains a Y-Coordinate which increases along; and Sheet 3: Cell A1 contains a value. Thus in effect, this is a Raster file made up of 3 Excel data sheets with a resolution of 25m with Sheet 1 representing the X-Axis, Sheet 2 the Y-Axis and sheet 3 a value within the cell.

Table structure excerpt - 200 Columns / 2000 Rows

Table "XCoord"

```
3544399.00  | 3544399.25 | 3544399.50 | 3544399.75 | 3544340.00  | ...etc
3544231.00  | 3544231.25 | 3544231.50 | 3544231.75 | 3544232.00  | ...etc 
3544135.00  | 3544135.25 | 3544135.50 | 3544135.75 | 3544136.00  | ...etc
```

Table "YCoord"

```
584449.00  | 584449.25 | 584449.50 | 584449.75 | 584449.00  | ...etc
584431.00  | 5844431.25 | 584431.50 | 584431.75 | 584431.00 | ...etc
584429.00  | 584429.25 | 584429.50 | 584429.75 | 584429.00  | ...etc
```

Table "Concentration"

```
0.0023  | 0.0025 | 0.0020 | 0.0027 | 0.0066  | ...etc
0.0011  | 0.0034 | 0.0056 | 0.0078 | 0.0033  | ...etc
0.0016  | 0.0026 | 0.0046 | 0.0003 | 0.0005  | ...etc
```

So you see, for the cells - the xcoord the ycoord and the concentration can be determined.
This is a raster built with 3 tables. My problem is how to map this into a GIS application. The values in the Table "concentration" are derivitives calculated out of other tables which include the plume-dispersion parameters. So in effect, this worksheet is a very ingenious way of calculating plumes without using expensive plume modelling software. I am using ArcGIS Advanced (Info), Safe fme, Excel.

I have to convert this into a raster image or point feature class. Does anyone know how I could translate this data out of excel?

Thanks for any tips,

RB

Comment: Could you maybe provide a very brief excerpt from each of these three tables? You first say each cell does "not contain", but later on you do say "cell .. contains..". Also, any preferred tools?

Comment: no problem...I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Do you have access to Python? (You should, it's installed with ArcGIS typically.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you've tried so far and what other technology's available to you, but there are many examples on the internet of using Excel + VBA to generate shapefiles, or using other programming languages like Python.

You may want to take a look at the [Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) site - there are some good examples there of how to interface between Excel and common GIS tools, for example, "[How can I convert an Excel file with X and Y columns to a shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327/how-can-i-convert-an-excel-file-with-x-y-columns-to-a-shapefile)". The basic info is there, you'll just need to adjust your specific code to work for having data across sheets instead of down rows.

If you wanted to convert your sheets data to a single sheet with `x`, `y`, `data` columns, you could write a VBA script to loop over each cell in the first sheet and extract the data from the same address on the other sheets.

To get a more specific answer, you'll need to post a more specific question regarding what method you're trying to do, and what part you need help on.